# mongodb: how to do backup of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I think someone has already suggested:

```
1. stop the mongod
2. backup the data directory
```

Is it reliable, I mean, ensure 100% success to restore?
And I can't find which directory stores the data... any command can help me to find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `mongod` process exits cleanly (that is, no crashes or `kill -9` stuff), then it is safe to copy data files somewhere.

If your current installation breaks (for example, data corruption due to unclean shutdown), you can delete its files, copy that backup over and start `mongod` again.

Default data directory is `/data/db`, but it may be set to another value in your config file. For example, I set it to `/var/lib/mongodb`.

You can also use `mongodump` to do a backup from a live server (this may impact performance). Use `mongorestore` to restore backups made by `mongodump`.

Comment: For: how to use **mongodump** and **mongorestore**, see a similar question and answer here for mongodump and mongorestore **syntax**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21309914/2728686

Answer (score 5):

At IGN we do hot backups via `mongodump` running as an hourly cron job, and take filer snapshots (NetApp storage) on a half-hourly basis. If your system is not too write heavy and you can afford write blocks, try using `fsync` and `lock` to flush the writes to the disk and prevent further writes. This can be followed by `mongodump` and upon completion you can unlock the db. Please note that you've to be admin to do so.

```
db.runCommand({fsync:1,lock:1})
```

Comment: What option would you recommend for write heavy db's?

Comment: Disk snapshots, or delayed slaves.

Comment: and what about backups in sharded environment?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/