# How to backup and restore the Mongodb database

Tags: c#, mongodb, backup, restore

How to use C# to backup and restore the Mongodb database? For now there is only an server to save the mongodb data, and I want to make an backup in case of the server is destroyed so that I can restore it.

Dose anybody know how to do that using C#?

Comment: If it is the question of one-time backup, then do you really need a programming language? Or you want to create an automated backup every n days/hours or something ?

Comment: yes,i just want to make an automatical backup program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want automated backups, there is an easier way than resorting to a full-fledged programming language:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-filesystem-snapshots/

As shown in the link, the below command would suffice. You may put it in a statup-script/daemon to execute it at regular frequencies:

Backup:

```
lvcreate --size 100M --snapshot --name mdb-snap01 /dev/vg0/mongodb
```

Restore:

```
lvcreate --size 1G --name mdb-new vg0
gzip -d -c mdb-snap01.gz | dd of=/dev/vg0/mdb-new
mount /dev/vg0/mdb-new /srv/mongodb
```

Comment: Also, this example applies to linux. If you are on windows, you may try mongodump & mongorestore utilities: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-binary-database-dumps/

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i has read the link and it is useful for me.

Comment: I used the command below:mongodump -h xxx.xx.xxx.xx -d test -o e:\dd to backup the mongodb data of reomte server in my local file, but always return me a socketException error:9001,do you know why?

Answer (score 10):

From the mongolab website (http://docs.mongolab.com/backups/) a useful/simple example:

To **backup** use **mongodump**:

```
% mongodump -h ds012345.mongolab.com:56789 -d dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword -o dumpdir
```

To **restore** use **mongorestore**:

```
% mongorestore -h ds023456.mongolab.com:45678 -d dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword dumpdir/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Take backup using mongodump use the following command

mongodump -d **database_name** -o **directory_where_mongodb_exists**

To restore use this command

mongorestore -d database_name mongodb_restore_directory

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I will emphasize on delineating a few caveats that I experienced while doing this for the first time. Hope this proves useful to somebody in the same situation. Although, the example uses the command line, the utilities are available out-of-the-box with the Mongo installation and can very well be used with C#.

First of, ensure that your MongoDB installation directory is in the environment path and you are able to access the **mongodump** command. MongoDB is normally installed in `~\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\<vr>\bin` on Windows.

Once the utility is accessible from CMD, navigate to the directory where you'd like to save (or dump) the backup.

Check the `mongodump --help` for options.
I used a simple (full) backup and restore. So, use the command and specify the required options. Here is an example:

**`mongodump /host:ds062199.mlab.com /port:62199 /username:mydbuser /password:mypwd /db:mydbname`**

The moment you hit enter, the utility will create BSON and metadata JSON backup files in a `dump/dbname` subdirectory.

Now, to restore, do the following. 
Note, I backed up a Mongo instance running on Azure (Mongo Labs) and restored it on my local machine as follows.
While in the same directory (on the cmd), execute the following:

**`mongorestore /host:localhost /port:27017`**

And it will create a new db, as the replica of the backup on the localhost mongodb instance.

Hope this helps!